# Updating value rpccorsdomain?

Tags: ethereum

How can I update rpccorsdomain value with my private node already mining?

Note
I have already setup it before to point to a url --rpccorsdomain "http://mywebsite.com" and need to update it to different value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can restart the RPC API using either the console or through a `curl` command.

In the console, you can issue an `admin.stopRPC()` and then restart it passing in the new cors value with `admin.startRPC(host, port, newCorsList, apis)`.

If you prefer using `curl`:

1. `curl -X POST --data '{"method": "admin_stopWS"}' nodeHostName:nodePortNumber`
2. `curl -X POST --data '{"method": "admin_startWS", "params": [host, port, cors, apis]}' nodeHostName:nodePortNumber`

The full list of available management APIs can be found [here](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/Management-APIs#list-of-management-apis).

Alternatively, you can just stop the node and restart it passing in the new cors list via command line options.